# How do change the wall switch for my ceiling fan from a variable fan/light combination to a single on/off switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I used to have a ceiling fan/light combination that was controlled by a wall switch the controlled both the fan speed and dimmed the light.

I bought a new fan/light that is controlled by a remote control device. Therefore, the wall switch must be converted to an on off switch only.  I am having a tough time determining which wires to use.

In the box behind the wall switch I have the following wires:

- One set of wires has a black wire, white wire, and ground.
- The second set of wires has a black wire, white wire, red wire and ground.
- currently, the two white wires are connected and capped together. In addition, the two ground wires are connected and turned into one ground wire.
- up at the ceiling, I have a set of four wires coming out… Red, black, white and green.   The remote transmitter can only except two wires, because it has the hole type connector, not the screw type connector.

Is anyone able to help me determine which wires to use at the wall switch, and which wires to use in the ceiling?  Do I cap off the unused wire at each end, or do I connect it to another wire somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you send us a picture of the remote unit and its make and model number?

Comment: I can send a picture later today along with any make/model information that might be on the remote or in the instruction booklet.  However, the remote came with the fan/light, which is the following model:  http://www.lowes.com/pd_599656-82939-40823_1z11xagZ1z140v4Z2z8vn__?productId=50261525&pl=1&Ntt=52+in+ceiling+fans+with+lights

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

- Cap off the red at both locations.
- The remaining black wires at the wall will connect to a standard single pole switch, and the remaining wires in the ceiling will connect to the receiver as directed by the manufactures instructions.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  The answer seems so easy now, but wasn't at the time when I asked it.